# C# Visual Studio выбрасывает обработанное мной исключение

Tags: c#, visual-studio, исключения

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема - один и тот же проект компилирую в режиме Debug на разных компьютерах и в одном случае стабильно выбрасывается перехваченное мной исключение, а в другом случае нет.

Код такой: создается сокет, асинхронно подключается к серверу и начинает прием данных от него. Если ответа от сервера нет, то я в продолжении задачи приема данных от сервера я ставлю заглушку, которая логгирует ошибку.

```
//Подключение:
  socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
  public async Task ConnectAsync(IPEndPoint remoteIpEp)
    {
        await Task.Factory.FromAsync(socket.BeginConnect(remoteIpEp, null, null), socket.EndConnect).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }



//Чтение строки:
public async Task<string> ReadLineAsync()
{
    using (NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(socket))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
           return await sr.ReadLineAsync();
        }
    }
}

//Чтение строки с таймаутом ожидания ответа
 public async Task<string> ReadLineAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        Task<string> rxTask = ReadLineAsync();

        if (await Task.WhenAny(rxTask, Task.Delay(timeout)).ConfigureAwait(false) != rxTask)
        {
            rxTask.Forget();
            socket.Close();
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }

        return await rxTask;
    }

    public static void Forget(this Task task)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.Exception != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Забытая задача завершена с ошибкой: {task.Exception}\r\n");
            }
        });
    }
```

Соединение с сервером устанавливается, но сервер не отправляет никакие данные (специально для инициирования таймаута ожидания ответа у клиента). На одном компьютере таймаут обрабатывается корректно, в окне студии Output я вижу сообщение об исключении.

Если тот же самый проект компилирую в на другом компьютере, то стабильно выскакивает исключение ObjectDisposedException в  System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult, SocketError& errorCode):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако я могу продолжить работу и приложение не закроется, в окно Output выведется лог метода Forget(..). Если запущу проект без отладчика и вне студии, то ошибок тоже никаких не будет.

Почему студия выбрасывает это исключение?

Comment: Спасибо, Геннадий! Правильно я понимаю, что эти настройки используются только для отладки, что бы принудительно выбрасывать исключения отпределенного типа? Для каких целей это может понадобиться?

Comment: @ГеннадийП стоит оформить ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Галочку напротив `Break when this exception type is thrown` снимите.
На том компьютере, где не останавливается скорее всего отключен останов на данном исключении.
Все настройки исключений находятся `Debug -> Exceptions`.